# find coordinates to draw square inside circle

Tags: html, html5-canvas

How to compute the starting co-ordinates to draw a square inside a cirle?

Function Draws the circular spectrum . 
Now help me to find the starting coordinates to  draw the rectangle inside the circle

```
Gradient.prototype.renderSpectrum = function() {
    var radius = this.width / 2;
    var toRad = (2 * Math.PI) / 360;
    var step = 1 / radius;

   this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    for(var i = 0; i < 360; i += step) {
        var rad = i * toRad;
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(' + i + ', 100%, 50%)';
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.moveTo(radius, radius);
        this.ctx.lineTo(radius + radius * Math.cos(rad), radius + radius * Math.sin(rad));
        this.ctx.stroke();
    }

   this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
   this.ctx.beginPath();
   this.ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius * 0.8, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
   this.ctx.closePath();
   return this.ctx.fill();

}
```

Function to draw the square

```
Gradient.prototype.renderGradient = function() {
  var color, colors, gradient, index, xy, _i, _len, _ref, _ref1;
  xy = arguments[0], colors = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
  gradient = (_ref = this.ctx).createLinearGradient.apply(_ref, [0, 0].concat(__slice.call(xy)));
  gradient.addColorStop(0, (_ref1 = colors.shift()) != null ? _ref1.toString() : void 0);
  for (index = _i = 0, _len = colors.length; _i < _len; index = ++_i) {
    color = colors[index];
    gradient.addColorStop(index + 1 / colors.length, color.toString());
  }
  this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  this.renderSpectrum();
  return this.ctx.fillRect(?, ?, this.width * 0.8, this.height * 0.8);
};
```

Answer (score 8):

To fit a square inside a circle you can use something like this (adopt as needed):

### [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/V7hrx/)

```
/**
 * ctx - context
 * cx/cy - center of circle
 * radius - radius of circle
*/
function squareInCircle(ctx, cx, cy, radius) {

    var side = Math.sqrt(radius * radius * 2),  // calc side length of square
        half = side * 0.5;                      // position offset

    ctx.strokeRect(cx - half, cy - half, side, side);
}
```

Just replace strokeRect() with fillRect().

Which will result in this (circle added for reference):

[image: Square in circle]

Adopting it for general usage:

```
function getSquareInCircle(cx, cy, radius) {

    var side = Math.sqrt(radius * radius * 2),  // calc side length of square
        half = side * 0.5;                      // position offset

    return {
        x: cx - half,
        y: cy - half,
        w: side,
        h: side
    }
}
```

Then in your method:

```
Gradient.prototype.renderGradient = function() {
  var color, colors, gradient, index, xy, _i, _len, _ref, _ref1;
  xy = arguments[0], colors = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
  gradient = (_ref = this.ctx).createLinearGradient.apply(_ref, [0, 0].concat(__slice.call(xy)));
  gradient.addColorStop(0, (_ref1 = colors.shift()) != null ? _ref1.toString() : void 0);
  for (index = _i = 0, _len = colors.length; _i < _len; index = ++_i) {
    color = colors[index];
    gradient.addColorStop(index + 1 / colors.length, color.toString());
  }
  this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  this.renderSpectrum();

  // supply the proper position/radius here:
  var square = getSquareInCircle(centerX, centerY, radius);

  return this.ctx.fillRect(square.x, square.y, square.w, square.h);
};
```

Comment: I tried the above code ..and modified accordingly but it is not  properly aligning inside the circle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/Ran5v/3/)

Comment: @BLPraveen you need to align it relative to the circle's center.

Comment: I tried and here is the [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/rjN5F/). I guess the side calculation must be Math.sqrt(radius * radius / 2)(to find sides from diagonal). I need to fill the rectanlge with HSL and HSV gradient not stroke. it is not generated properly

Comment: How to generate HSL and HSV in the rectangle inside the circle?

Comment: @BLPraveen I believe that would be another question - please consider opening a new question. To fill just replace stroke with fill. Set your gradient as fillStyle before calling fill.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I computed the co ordinates to draw square inside a circle

1)Get the coordinates of a inner circle at 135 degree
 using the  formula

x = rad + rad * Math.cos(135 * ( 2 Math.PI / 360);

y = rad - rad * Math.sin(135 * ( 2 Math.PI / 360);

2) then pyhthogoram therom to find the width if the square

```
width = Math.sqrt(rad * rad / 2);
```