# How do you draw a picture of a square inscribed in a circle with radius R?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Is there any way you would draw a square inscribed a circle, with the square’s corners tangent to the circumference of the circle and having radius R? It should look something like the image attached. Of course, the rectangle is supposed to be square.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function draw() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('circle');

  if (canvas.getContext) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const X = canvas.width / 2;
    const Y = canvas.height / 2;
    const R = 50;
    const angle = 45 * (Math.PI / 180);
    const G = Math.sin(angle) * R;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, R, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#0000FF';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body onload="draw()">
  <div style="text-align:center;" , style="position: absolute">
    <canvas id="circle" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: This might help: [find coordinates to draw square inside circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978812/find-coordinates-to-draw-square-inside-circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to make the circle fit the canvas dimensions, then calculate accordingly, to get the variables for the circle and the square. The canvas is a square so I don't see why we would need two different variables for the height and width. `canvas.width = canvas.height` so we can just use `canvas.width` to do all of the calculations.

[image]

```js
function draw() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('circle');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // Circle
    const r = canvas.width/2,
          angle = 45*(Math.PI/180),
          g = Math.sin(angle)*r;

    drawCircle(canvas.width, r);

    function drawCircle(diameter, radius){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(diameter/2, diameter/2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#0000FF';
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    // Square  
    const squareWidth = Math.sqrt(2*r**2),
          startX = (canvas.width - squareWidth) / 2,
          startY = startX;
    
    drawSquare(startX, startY, squareWidth);

    function drawSquare(x, y, width){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x, y, width, width)
      ctx.stroke();          
    }
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body onload="draw()">
  <div style="text-align:center;" , style="position: absolute">
    <canvas id="circle" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to your draw function:

```
            const cos45 = 0.7071;
            // squareSide = cos45 * R * 2;
            const halfOfSquareSide = cos45 * R;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(X - halfOfSquareSide, Y - halfOfSquareSide, halfOfSquareSide * 2 , halfOfSquareSide * 2);
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
            ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).